# Setting and clearing the defautValues of an input in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on a form that adds or edits an item and send it as an object to the server. I used react-bootstrap forms to handle this issue with redux and here is how it is implemented :

```
<FormGroup className="form-group col-md-12">
          <Label className="create-item">Price</Label>
          <Input className="form-control" name="price"
                 defaultValue={item? 
                 item.price : ' '}
                 onChange={(e) => dispatch(setFormValue(e))} required />
</FormGroup>
```

And here is how I handle my onchange through redux :

```
export function setFormValue(field) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: types.SET_FORM_VALUE, payload: field })
    };
}

// And this is the reducer function that modifies the input
case types.SET_FORM_VALUE:
     return {
         ...state,
         form: {
              ...state.form,
              [action.payload.target.name]: action.payload.target.value.trimStart()
                }
            };
```

I fetch the data of the item so that the user can edit the data inside the input. And, I use onchange to make it work out. The thing is, when I open the form to add a new item, it works properly as all inputs are empty. Yet, when editing an item, the input fields are populated with the old values of the item and when I edit and submit them, only the data that I edit are sent to the server but others not. Also, when I finish and try to clear the default values from the form, it doesn't work properly. How can I fix this? Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? How do you handle the change of your input fields with redux?

Comment: @Dax Sure. I added the action and also the reducer function.

Comment: I think your old values are still in your redux state when you try to edit an item, so they get populated with the values from the state. You would need an action that clears your form values after the form is successfully submitted or closed. Not sure how you currently handle your submit or how you pass your form state to the form